# invalid(empty) response with Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

AM building a USSD application, in Django with this API https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/7705958/UyrEhaLQ#intro. I get the responses from the API and initialize the data to be processed. But I don't get the menu (MSG) to display on the user phone successfully. The error I get is **invalid(empty) response**.  This is the response to the user’s request. The content provider should provide a response to the request in the same format.

```
USERID = This is the ID provided by NALO to the client
MSISDN = The mobile number of the user
MSG =This is a mandatory parameter that holds the message to be displayed on the user’s phone
MSGTYPE = This indicates whether the session should continue or be terminated (True/false)
```

```
@csrf_exempt
def ussd(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        html = "<html><body>Nothing here baby!</body></html>"
        return HttpResponse(html)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        url = "https://99c9-102-176-94-213.ngrok.io/ussd"
        response_data = json.loads(request.body)
        code_id   = response_data["USERID"]
        serviceCode  = response_data["MSISDN"]
        type = response_data["MSGTYPE"]
        session_id = response_data["SESSIONID"]
        text         = response_data["USERDATA"]
        msg = ""
        if text == "":
            msg = "Welcome To TEST Dev"
        elif text == "1":
            msg = "This is Test Two"
        payload ={
                "USERID": code_id,
                "MSISDN": serviceCode,
                "MSGTYPE": type,
                "USERDATA": text,
                "SESSIONID": session_id,
                "MSG": msg,
            }
        headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
        response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload))
        return HttpResponse(response, status=200)
```

Comment: @NKSM Any help with this?

Comment: @AnkitTiwari any help with this?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem any help with this ?